# How can I list results from a mysql table bottom to top

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to list results from a mysql table bottom to top using orderby. I know there are very similar questions to this, any there any I can do this without keeping track of the date.

Comment: Do you mean you want to sort the results? If so, you can use `order by`. Lots of information on how to do this on the web.. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/order-by-optimization.html

Comment: sample data required
????

Comment: Please post a [mcve] with sample data.

Answer (score 1):

If you could post some more information on table/code and desired output I could try to give a more exact answer. If you just want to use order by and change the order in which its sorted. By Default MySQL uses ASC you can add DESC afterwards to switch the ordering like so:

So if we have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  first_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  last_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(ID)
 );

 INSERT INTO users (first_name, last_name) VALUES ('John', 'Doe');
 INSERT INTO users (first_name, last_name) VALUES ('Mary', 'Lou');
 INSERT INTO users (first_name, last_name) VALUES ('Alex', 'Avery');
 INSERT INTO users (first_name, last_name) VALUES ('James', 'Peach');
```

And we want the output to be ordered: Peach, Doe, Lou, Avery instead of Avery, Doe, Lou, Peach we would do:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name 
FROM   users
ORDER  by last_name DESC;
```

I have added the sql fiddle for you to see:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ddc6a0/2